# Change Repeating Reminder's Content Daily

Tags: swift

In my app, I ask the user to set up a repeating reminder. In this reminder, I would like the body to say something different each day. For example, I have over 500 quotes in my Firebase db and I want my reminder to show a new quote each day. How can I programmatically change the body of the reminder each day without user interaction?

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let identifier = "myApp"
    content.title = "myApp"
    content.body = "I want to change this programatically each day"
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: reminderTime.date), repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){
        (error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("here error in setting up notification")
            print(error!)
        } 
        else
        {
            print("notification scheduled")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not handle the `LocalNotification` showing moment. You just tell the system when to show your notification and the system show it without calling your application.

But you can add multiple notification requests at once ([up to 64](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification)). For example, all notifications for the next month and update your notifications on app launch. Just make sure that your notification requests has **different identifiers**.

For example, you create 30 notifications and user receives them for 5 days. Then he opens your app and you add 5 notifications more.

If you'll need to remove some of the pending notifications, you can make it using the following method.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to schedule more notifications without the user interacting with the app or notification (in the background)?

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean. Once a user chooses the notification time, you can create up to `64` scheduled notifications with different parameters. For example, one for each day or an hour. And once the user changes the notification time, you can delete all pending notifications and create new.

Comment: What I mean is: The user interacts with the app for the first time, so I set up the 64 notifications there. After that, lets say the user never touches a notification or visits the app again, so the 64 notifications have now been shown. Do you know how I can set up 64 more notifications if my app is never revisted?

Comment: The only way I can imagine is to send a `RemoteNotification` to your app that will trigger specific callback that you going to add. At that callback, you might silently create new notifications.